# How do I create a form with a textbox when writing a Wordpress Plugin/

Tags: wordpress

I can't seem to understand how to create a form with the Wordpress Settings API that only includes a textbox where the user can insert some code and then click a button that says "Save Changes" For reference I am going for something like this:
[Insert Headers an Footers Plugin Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTu3E.png)

My current code: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/l8JjhNYvp6NPFG1saEsc4Q

Comment: Do you want to create a new settings page in wordpress or just create a textbox which shows when editing a page/post (metabox)?

Comment: I would like to know how to do both ways if you can help but I have already created a new settings page. Sorry forgot to add that. Here is my current code:
https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/l8JjhNYvp6NPFG1saEsc4Q

Comment: Can you please put the link for your code to your question? You are missing the `add_settings_field`. You can read more about it here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field

Comment: add_settings_field( $id, $title, $callback, $page, $section, $args );


This is the thing I have to add but I am still not sure on what to change these to from my own code.

Comment: Take a look at this [graphical representation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API#Graphical_Representation_of_where_all_those_code_should_go:), which should help you understand the `add_settings_field()` function, and hopefully other things in or related to the [WordPress Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).

Comment: I don't need that add_settings_field then because I just looked at that graphical representation. I'm not trying to add extra settings to the Settings > Reading >  section.

Comment: That was just an example, actually, of how you can use the WordPress Settings API. The `add_settings_field()` function can be used to add settings fields to *any* pages and not just the "Reading" settings section/page. Nevertheless, I hope the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) has helped you. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one example of creating an options page:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

```
<?php
// create custom plugin settings menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_cool_plugin_create_menu');

function my_cool_plugin_create_menu() {

    //create new top-level menu
    add_menu_page('My Cool Plugin Settings', 'Cool Settings', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'my_cool_plugin_settings_page' , plugins_url('/images/icon.png', __FILE__) );

    //call register settings function
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_my_cool_plugin_settings' );
}


function register_my_cool_plugin_settings() {
    //register our settings
    register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'new_option_name' );
    register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'some_other_option' );
    register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'option_etc' );
}

function my_cool_plugin_settings_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h1>Your Plugin Name</h1>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">New Option Name</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="new_option_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('new_option_name') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Some Other Option</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="some_other_option" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('some_other_option') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Options, Etc.</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="option_etc" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('option_etc') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php submit_button(); ?>

</form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

You can also use another method an use functions `add_settings_section` and `add_settings_field` which both need a callback function: http://qnimate.com/wordpress-settings-api-a-comprehensive-developers-guide/

Comment: Thanks for actually posting code so I can look at it.